# Confusion in bitwise operation

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

Here I am trying to convert h = 010 to h = 001 (via right shift operator) and then using the 'and' operator with  1, I wanna print yes, but I don't know why it is printing NO.

```
 int h = 010;
 h = h>>1;
 
 if(h & 1){
     cout<< "YES";
 }
 else{
     cout << "NO";
 }
```

Comment: iirc, having a 0 prefix gives you octal, not binary

Comment: In this case, h is 10, not 0b10, so you should learn how to define a binary number first.

Comment: Use `int h = 0b010;` instead. You have an octal number literal there.

Comment: oh yeah lol thnx